# Add a request header from the url, to support multi-tenancy

Tags: web-services, wcf

**Background**

I have an existing service contract which cannot be modified.  The implementation of the service is code which I support and can change.

Currently, the service supports a single tenant, and multiple instances of this service are hosted, for example http://foo-tenant1.com/service.svc and http://foo-tenant2.com/service.svc

Now I want to change the service to support multiple tenants, with a single service.  For example, the service hosted at address: http://foo.com/service.svc and support for multiple tenants by adding a tenant id to the address;

for example:

If WCF can somehow support wildcard routing:

http://foo.com/tenant1/service.svc and http://foo.com/tenant2/service.svc etc...

or if it can somehow support query strings:

http://foo.com/service.svc?tenant1 and http://foo.com/service.svc?tenant2 etc...

or some other way...

The reason for this is that the clients calling this will not have any concept of a tenant.  From the client's perspective there is only a Url for each tenant.

**Question**

How can I host a WCF service with a "catch all" endpoint like this? Or can I do this with routing or url rewriting?  I can then get the tenant Id into a request header, and modify the service code to support multi-tenants.

I can then change the service code to read from the request header and support the tenant Id.

Comment: When you say that you can not modify Service Contract, does that mean you don't have access to code?

Comment: Moreover, http://foo.com/tenant/service.svc and http://foo.com/tenant1/service.svc means two different WCF services which cannot be achieved with one service. I think you want to refer to WCF REST service where you can do it like.... http://foo.com/Service.svc/tenant and http://foo.com/Service.svc/tenant1

Comment: @HarmeetBhamra I can modify the service code, but not the contract because I cannot modify the clients

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 - If you can modify the service code, you have a lot more flexibility.   You can modify the existing service contract and add new methods - this would be a non-breaking change for existing clients.  As long as the methods the existing clients are expecting don't change, you can do anything you want in the actual implementation.

Comment: @Tim I can't modify the clients and they can only call the existing methods, thus can't create new methods as no clients will be able to call these

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 - Existing clients can still call the service, even if you modify it with new methods.  The only time that won't work is if the clients need to call the new methods, but I'm not clear in whether that's the case or not.

Comment: @Tim "new" clients also need to call existing methods, not the new methods, so creating new methods will not help in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the code for the service or can't change the code, you'll need to think a little outside the box.  One option would be to create separate applications inside IIS and hopefully your service allows you to change web.config values such that you can configure the service to look at a different database (if that's what is backing it).

But if the web.config route doesn't capture all of your variables, you might have to think about doing an IHttpModule.  Injecting that early enough in the service stack would give you options to do what you will with the URL, though you still don't have control over the code that subsequently gets called unless you completely override what gets called and don't call the base method to continue execution.

You could also write a page for 404's that you have control over the backing code such that you can then do something dynamically at that point.  You would just need to modify the web.config file to point 404's to the URL and execute it.  Though be warned, that is all 404s.

Finally, if the code that implements the service contract can be removed, you could drop a DLL onto the server that implements the contract and update the web.config file to point to this DLL instead.  Though this might not be possible if the DLL that you remove also removes a significant portion of other code.

If you don't have access to the code, you are going to have a tough time as all of these solutions are pretty advanced concepts.

Comment: I can modify the service code, just not the contract.  The clients can only call existing service methods.